# Python 3 + Graph FB Api: How to upload photo to Facebook with public privacy?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, multipartform-data

I am using following code to upload photos to Facebook but I cannot set photos to public. I always get this response from Facebook:

```
privacy must contain a valid privacy 'value'
```

So, how to fix it ? Thank you :)

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/photos' +'?access_token=' + token

data = {'privacy': {'value':'EVERYONE'}}
files = {'file': open('304992328824529136_239074999.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url=url, data = data,  files = files, verify = False)
```

Comment: What is the default privacy setting for the app? Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications to check. You can not set a “broader” privacy value than that.

Comment: Hello @CBroe, the default privacy setting is public